# Timers in vxWorks 6.9

Tags: c++, c, c++98, vxworks

In vxWorks 6.9 you can create timers, which are really just wrappers for a watchdog. You supply these guys a function pointer, a delay, and up to one parameter, and after the delay the function is called with the parameter. However, it is called in the interrupt context. This (for some reason) means you cannot call any "blocking" functions or the system literally crashes. You cannot call `printf` and you cannot call upon an object's public function, ie you cannot do this:

```
void Foo::WdCallback(Foo *foo){
    foo->DoThing();
}

wdStart(wd, 16, (FUNCPTR)Foo::WdCallback, (_Vx_usr_arg_t)my_foo_ptr);
```

as it will also crash for reasons I don't understand.

What other way can we create a timer/timeout in vxWorks so that we can actually do something useful with the callback? One method I have seen is using a message queue - the watchdog function will call upon a message queue send function. However this means that a task must be created to dequeue that message queue somewhere else. I've also read that the watchdog callback could give a semaphore allowing a task to continue, but that means we have to create a task for every single timer-based function we want..

It looks like no matter what road we take with watchdogs, or timers, in vxWorks, we have to create an entire task just to be able to handle the watchdog callback due to the interupt context. There has to be a less ridiculous way to do this. Is there a purely C++ way to write a timer? Or a simpler vxWorks implementation?

Comment: member functions have an implicit parameter for `this` but the location of that parameter in the ordering is implementation dependent AFAIK.

Comment: 'that means we have to create a task for every single timer-based function we want', no, you do not.  You only need one task that maintains a list of timeout structs ordered by timeout-time.  This task sets the interrupt timer to fire after the nearest timeout from the head of the list.  The structs could have function pointers, or instances derived from a 'timeout' class that has a  irtual timeout method.

Comment: 'but how can I safely add/delete/whatever items in the list if the timeout thread could preempt at any time and remove the item at the head of the list that it just timed out' - you request the timeout task to do that stuff by shoving timeout instances onto a thread-safe 'command' queue and signaling the semaphore.  When the timeout task runs, it now does two things: check the command queue for any new timeout requests and check the timeout list head to see if it has timed out yet.  If so, handle it, if not, recalculate the remaining time, set the interrupt timer and wait on the semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

C++ shall not be used for function being executed in an interrupt context. The watchdog here is executed in the context of the system tick interrupt.

If you want to keep C++ code, make sure that no new/delete operation will be performed and you would need to compile the code with addition flags (this should be documented in the VxWorks Programmer's Guide at the C++ section => -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions).